# What is the best practice for creating a NuGet package from a project built using RazorGenerator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, razorgenerator

I have an MVC-ish project that includes pre-compiled, reuseable views created by the [RazorGenerator](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator) tool. This generates a reusable shell for other websites. I can successfully include that project in another project in the same solution.

I want to be able to reuse the shell project in other MVC projects in their own solutions. I believe packaging and distributing the shell via an internal NuGet server is the best way to go.

I created an initial NuGet package for the project following NuGet's [instructions](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/creating-a-package). This package has too much in it. I am working to trim it down.

Does anyone have a set of best practices for creating and reusing a generated shell like this?

Comment: I'm editing the NUPKG file manually. It looks like nuget pack grabs the Content, Images, Scripts, and Views directories and adds them to the content folder for MVC projects. It also add Web.config as a transform file which is probably OK along with the Global.asax which I would not want. Can I edit what is included in content without creating a whole new directory structure and running pack from there?

Comment: So far, I am not certain how to modify NuGet's automatic packaging of a MVC5 project. Currently, I am editing the NUPKG file with 7Zip and removing the pieces that NuGet adds and I don't want for redistribution: Views dir, Global.asax, and some other items. I tried creating the package directly from the NUSPEC file. I am not sure how to include the Web.config as a .transform file.